# fab hello returns "No module named win32api" only in virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, fabric, activepython

I can run fab (fabric) in windows but not after running virtualenv/Scripts/activate.bat.

I am running ActivePython 2.7.2.5 with the latest fabric.
Tried using pip and pypy in and out of virtualenv.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Most likely your virtualenv is installed without site packages and win32api is installed only for the primary Python interpreter site packages.

Comment: That was the problem. Rather than using: virtualenv --no-site-packages ve, I used virtualenv ve. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this command to include the missing win32api site packages:

```
python virtualenv.py --system-site-packages virtualenv
```

As Mikko mentioned, the "--system-site-packages" switch is what's needed.  See the [virtualenv --system-site-packages documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#the-system-site-packages-option) for more information.